# Cancel mid-season

Tags: word-usage

If a show was cancelled abruptly,  will it be natural to say:

> The show was cancelled mid-season.

Will it be used only when half of the episodes have already aired?  Or can it be used when a show is cancelled after 2-5 episodes or maybe 10? (Like a season of 30 episodes,  though if a show was off air after a few episodes there's no way to know for sure how many episodes were going to be a part of the first season,  so can "mid-season" be used for 2-5 episodes as well?)

**And is the description natural?  If not,  what's a more natural way to describe my question to make it more clear and idiomatic?**

Comment: If it's cancelled really early (2-5 out of 30 feels like this) I might lean towards saying "It was cancelled after only a few episodes." Otherwise your sentence feels perfectly natural to me. I don't think describing this situation as mid-season would be *wrong*, but if something is cancelled that early you probably want to focus on the earliness itself.

Comment: I'd say mid-season would cover between 1/3rd of the way through to 2/3rds (Possibly even 1/4 to 3/4)

Comment: If you wanted to be less specific, you could say "part way through the season". This could cover anything from the 2nd to the 2nd to last

Comment: Thank you @Bee for your reply.  Could you please use it in a sentence?  It would really help me to understand its use properly. 

Comment: Like: "The show was cancelled party way through." And what about: "The show was cancelled half-way through. "

Comment: "The show was cancelled part way through the season" or "The show was cancelled part of the way through the season". Half-way heavily implies it was pretty much 50% of the way through

Comment: But @Bee dictionaries used "part way through" to mean "half way through,  mid-season"....    https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/part-way-through

Comment: Mid-way through is a subset of part way through, in my opinion. [Here is a better definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partway)

Comment: It may be abrupt and it may be mid season. One doesn't imply the other in any way. (It could be cancelled abruptly at the start of the season or the end of the season. It could also be cancelled with a lot of advance notice in mid season.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is perfectly clear. In English, when talking about the point at which something occurred during a season of a program, there's no standard as to how many episodes can refer to "mid-season". Some shows have 10 episodes a season, so mid-season could be like 5 or 6 episodes in, while other shows have 30 episodes a season, so mid-season could be like 17 or 18 episodes in.

Generally, the periods we would refer to would be

- Before a season
- At the beginning of a season -> First few episodes; to some people, maybe the first quarter
- Mid-season - > **Arguably anything except the first or last episode of the season**
- At the end of a season -> Last few episodes, perhaps the last quarter
- After a season

Comment: And will it be okay to use "in" this way: "How many episodes are in the first season" To mean "How many episodes are part of the first season"?

Comment: And what about "The show was off air after a few episodes." to mean "The show was taken off air after a few episodes". Is it okay to remove "taken" to mean that the show doesn't broadcast anymore?

Comment: What do you think about the two replies above?

Comment: A native speaker would probably say "How many episodes are in the first season?". Another way would be to ask "The first season is made up of how many episodes?". I wouldn't use "part of" here. For your second question, "off air" tends to describe when a broadcast is terminated/turned off. For ex., "The show ran from 6-7pm, then the network went off the air." It's more for describing the end of an event. In your example, depending on your intent, I think "The show was cancelled after a few episodes" or "The network stopped airing the show after a few episodes" would fit better.

Comment: And what do you think about "taken off air"?  Because I too think that "is off air" will be more likely to express the present scenario,  not that it has been cancelled.....  

Comment: I think "The show was taken off the air part way through the season" would be understood by any native speaker.

Comment: Will "part way" imply "half-way" Or does it mean "any episode,  not necessarily "halfway through"?

Comment: "Part way" would imply the word "partially", which is generally referring to an unspecified fraction. "Midway" or "halfway" would imply half or about half. In this case, "part way through the season" would mean the same thing as "mid-season", as they're both implying "some point in between the beginning and the end of the season".